# Stale data in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, professional-edition

I'm working on a Professional Edition org and experiencing some strange things in Process Builder and I hope this can be clarified. I have created a minimal example, a custom object "Beep__c" which has a Name field and one custom field "Boop__c". **UPDATE: Making this example even more minimal as it still demonstrates the situation.**

Process is invoked when a Beep is created or updated.

Criterion: `[Beep__c].Name != NULL`

Immediate Actions: 1) `Update Borp = [Beep__c].Name & " Beep!"`
and

2) Update `Beep Name = [Beep__c].Borp__c & " Beeep!";` evaluate next criteria

**Test 1**

- Edit an existing record, setting Name = A, Borp = B, save.
- Expected: Name = A Beep! Beeep!, Borp = A Beep!
- Actual result: Name = B Beeep!, Borp = A Beep!
- *So even though I've already modified the value of Name during this Process, whenever I try to retrieve that field again I always get the value of Name from when the Process started.*

**Test 2**

- Edit an existing record, setting Name = A, Borp is null, save.
- Expected: Name = A Beep! Beeep!, B = A Beep!
- Actual result is as expected
- *So this time, because I saved null/empty to Borp, the value I updated the field with in Process Builder is correctly seen later in the Process.*

So I have concluded so far:

- If Process Builder updates a field on the current record that was non-null, any attempt to access it later in the process will only find the original value.
- But if PB updates a field on the current record that was null, any attempt to reference it later in the process will find the value that was saved to the field.

So if I want to be able to overwrite a field value in Process Builder *and* find that updated value again later in the Process, am I just out of luck? There are after all no temporary variables like in Flows (and I can't get Flows in Professional Edition).